# Typescript - React.FC is any and not checking props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I've created a `reactjs` applicaiton using `npx create-react-app myapp --template typescript`

My created component

```
import React from 'react';

interface IPerson {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}

const Person:React.FC<IPerson> = (props:IPerson) => {
    const {name, age} = props;

    return <div>{name} {age}</div>;
}
```

If I don't pass the required props even then typescript is not throwing any error. Even if I run the application I am not getting any kind of warning or error.

```
 <Person name='xyz' />
```

Above line supposed to throw error. But it is working fine.

I tried to find the cause but haven't found something which can fix this. All I found is when I hover one `React.FC` it shown of type `any` instead of type `IPerson`.
[image]

It would be really appreciated if someone can put some light on it.

Comment: That is bizarre, I even doubled checked my own code locally, and that exact use case should throw warnings. Potentially your IDE is not set to honour the TypeScript rules? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Check that all react typings are installed correctly and remove the entire node_modules folder and run `npm install` again. You can also try to use `React.FunctionComponent` instead of FC.

Comment: @RohanBüchner I am using VSCode and it is up to date.

Comment: @Phil running npm install again fixed the issue. I was getting another error while running npm install. I believe when I created the app, same error came and due to which type checking was not working.

Comment: that pleases me to hear! (: I had exactly the same thing some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `npm install` again then I noticed that following error was there in terminal:

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
```

[image]

I did following steps to fix this:

```
xcode-select --print-path // this will give path of xcode-select install. use it to remove it;

sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

xcode-select --install // install it again
```

After the above steps when I ran `npm install` VSCode started throwing error if required props are missing.